# convert a string to a string of numbers representing where each letter is located in the alphabet ('a' is 1, 'z' is 26)

Tags: javascript

i need to create a function alphabetIndexer that takes a string as an argument and returns a string of numbers representing where each letter is located in the alphabet ('a' is 1, 'z' is 26). If the character is upper-case, multiply its position by 2. All characters in the string that are not letters should be ignored.

```
function alphabetIndexer(str){
    let alphabet = 'abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    let arr = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        if(alphabet.includes(str[i].toLowerCase())){
            if(str[i] === str[i].toUpperCase()){
                arr.push(alphabet.indexOf((str[i] +1)*2))
            } else {
            arr.push(alphabet.indexOf(str[i]) +1);
            }
        }
    }
            return arr.join(' ');
}
```

I cant get the UpperCase letter position multiplied by 2;

in a test case "Hello World" it should return "16 5 12 12 15 46 15 17 12 4"
but my function returns [ -1, 5, 12, 12, 15, -1, 15, 18, 12, 4 ]

Comment: On a side note, you might want to rethink this with using character codes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt -- The `codePointAt()` method gives you a number that represents the character at the given index, e.g. 65 for `A`. It can work faster than searching a string for each character.

Answer (score 5):

You've made a great start, you've just got your parentheses wrong. This:

```
arr.push(alphabet.indexOf((str[i] +1)*2))
```

should be

```
arr.push((alphabet.indexOf(str[i]) +1)*2)
```

which would be clearer if:

- You put `str[i]` in a variable instead of looking it up every time
- Used spaces around operators

:-)

I.e.:

```
arr.push((alphabet.indexOf(ch) + 1) * 2)
```

The second problem is that you only do the `toLowerCase` thing when doing the `includes` check but not later when you do `indexOf`. You need to do it in all three places you look through `alphabet`:

```js
function alphabetIndexer(str) {
  let alphabet = 'abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (alphabet.includes(str[i].toLowerCase())) {
      if (str[i] === str[i].toUpperCase()) {
        arr.push((alphabet.indexOf(str[i].toLowerCase()) + 1) * 2); // ***
      } else {
        arr.push(alphabet.indexOf(str[i].toLowerCase()) + 1);       // ***
      }
    }
  }
  return arr.join(' ');
}
console.log(alphabetIndexer("Hi there"));
```

For what it's worth, here are some minor changes I'd make (without changing your overall approach):

```js
"use strict";
function alphabetIndexer(str) {
  let alphabet = 'abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  let arr = [];
  for (let ch of str) { // Strings are iterable
    // Only search `alphabet` once
    let index = alphabet.indexOf(ch.toLowerCase());
    if (index !== -1) {
      if (ch === ch.toUpperCase()) {
        arr.push((index + 1) * 2);
      } else {
        arr.push(index + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return arr.join(' ');
}
console.log(alphabetIndexer("Hi there"));
```

You might also consider using `const` for "variables" you never change (amusingly, that's all of them in that code; changing the *state* of `arr` isn't changing the content of the variable `arr`).

Comment: thank you! even after fixing parentheses mistake, the function still returns '-2 5 12 12 15 -2 15 18 12 4'   first -2 should be 16, and the second -2 should be 46;

Comment: Eddie :)  
Thank you for the tip on codePointAt() - I am looking into it now.
And thank you for the cleaned up and easer to read version of the function :)

Comment: @AliciaK - There was a second error (which I inadvertently fixed in my version above). You only do the `toLowerCase` thing when doing the `includes` check but not later when you do `indexOf`. You need to do it in all three places you look through `alphabet` (http://jsfiddle.net/ykoxLn43/). (Which is why only doing that **once**, as above, is the better idea.)

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.push(alphabet.indexOf((str[i] +1)*2))
```

This is obviously where the mistake. Are you sure your * 2 should be inside the indexOf argument? Try this:

```
arr.push((alphabet.indexOf(str[i]) +1)*2);
```

EDIT: It's also a good idea to think about why it's giving you -1. I'm not too sure since I'm no Java**Script** Expert myself.

Comment: Sorry. I need my evening coffee, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ASCII value using `.charCodeAt()` and then subtract the offset from 0.

```js
const CAPS_OFFSET  = 64;
const LOWER_OFFSET = 96;
const ALPHA_ONLY   = /[a-zA-Z]/;

console.log( alphabetIndexer('Hello World') );


function alphabetIndexer(str) {  

  let arr = Array.from(str, letter=>{
    if (!ALPHA_ONLY.test(letter)) return;
    let ascii = letter.charCodeAt(0)
    return ascii > LOWER_OFFSET ? ascii - LOWER_OFFSET : (ascii - CAPS_OFFSET)*2;
  });
  
  return arr.join(' ')
}
```

Comment: the pattern `[...str].map(cb)` would be better with `Array.from(str, cb)`, because it uses iterables and maps at the same time.

Comment: Updated w/ your mastery recommendation